Problems with the use of el-icon in element-plus
I'm developing on top of a code with a paragraph like this
<template>
  <el-icon v-if="icon && icon.includes('el-icon')" class="sub-el-icon" />
  <SvgIcon v-else-if="icon" :icon-class="icon" />
  <span v-if="title">{{ translateRouteTitle(title) }}</span>
</template>

But el-icon doesn't show up properly, which confuses me
I looked up the official docs but didn't find a similar usage
I want el-icon to dynamically display different icons based on the name of the icon I pass in
icon is a variable, and that's what I'd like it to look like \<el-button type="primary" :icon="Search"\> 查询 \</el-button\>，This code in the same project can display the icon, which is the magnifying glass, but in the code in my body, even if icon="Search", it is still not displayed, it is simply blank.
I'm also testing with this code：\<el-icon :icon="icon" /\>，There was also no response.

includes is a Javascript function that checks whether an array or string contains an element or substring. For example:


console.log(['el-icon','something','else'].includes('el-icon')); //true
console.log('\<el-button type="primary" :icon="Search"\> 查询 \</el-button\>'.includes('el-icon')); //false
console.log('\<el-icon :icon="icon" /\>'.includes('el-icon')); //true



Your first example of \<el-button type="primary" :icon="Search"\> 查询 \</el-button\> does not contain the substring of el-icon so it is expectable to not fulfill the test. Your second example of \<el-icon :icon="icon" /\> contains it, but since includes fails for this too, you will need to debug and find out more of the type of icon, that will very likely point you toward the solution. If you get an error in the console, stating that includes is not a function of your object, then you are calling it in an invalid manner. Otherwise, if you do not get an error, then icon is not what you think it is. You can only get further information if you debug.
